# how to debug PHP that runs passively in the background?

Tags: javascript, php, echo

I'm trying to do a project that someone else has already done. This is a link to the [blog post](http://blogs.wcode.org/2015/04/footfall-a-camera-based-people-counting-system-for-under-60/) and [code](https://github.com/WatershedArts/Footfall).

I'm new to PHP, javascript and web development, so what I'm trying to figure out is how to debug this code and figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm able to use alert messages in the main-events.js file to debug and they pop up on my screen, but none of the echo messages in the dbconnect.php for example produce any result in my web browser. Even when I open that dbconnect.php file directly in my web browser it just displays the code contained in that file. Am I going about this right way? Or is there a better way to debug PHP code?

Comment: `"how to debug php"` - xdebug, `"Even when I open that dbconnect.php file directly in my web browser it just displays the code contained in that file"` Sounds like you havent set up your server properly - Can you run a very basic script like `<?php echo 'Hello World';?>`

Comment: start by reading some debugging tutorials. It's as important to know how and what debugging resources are available to you as it is in how to generate the actual code

Comment: @Steve I just tried to run that Hello World script and it looks like that is my issue, it just displayed that code.

Comment: What webserver are you using? What OS?

Comment: It's CentOS, not sure on the web server, I don't currently have admin privileges on the server I'm using so I'll just have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using `print_r()` or `var_dump()` function instead `echo` to see the result from dbconnect.php, because sometimes `echo` did not print the invisible value.